# Removing a (possibly) incorrectly wired multiway switch

Tags: electrical, multiway-switch

I am in the UK. My bathroom has a set of recessed LED downlights which are controlled by two switches. A dimmer switch outside the room and a pull cord switch inside the room.

The switches are configured such that both switches must be 'on' for the light to be on.

I had always assumed that the reason for this was that the switches were simply wired in series rather than using a three wire system, perhaps because the pull cord switch was added later.

I now want to remove the dimmer switch entirely. This is because I get a flicker from my LED downlights, and in any case the dimmer switch is inconveniently located. The pull cord is enough.

Anyway, to my surprise when I looked at the wiring of the dimmer switch, there are three wires connected. Two into the 'Common' terminal and one into the 'L1' terminal. This configuration does not match any of the wiring diagrams I have found for two way switching.

So my questions are:

1. Is the wiring likely incorrect? Or am I missing something?
2. To remove the switch from the circuit, leaving just the pull cord, is it as simple as using something like a three-way Wago connector to connect the three wires?

[image: Dimmer switch wiring]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A three-way Wago connector will do, because it will replicate what happens when the dimmer switch is closed.**

The fact that only two of the terminals are populated isn't an issue. The L2 terminal would only be used in a two-way switching scenario, but you've stated that both switches need to be on for the light to be powered (which isn't what you'd get with two-way switching).

From what I can see (three neutrals joined together by a terminal block, but only two lives, with the third going to the dimmer switch instead), the two yellow wires are used together as a single switched live, going to the pull switch and light. The fact that the two yellow wires are fitted to the same terminal means they must be electrically connected, no matter what the state of the switch.

My guess is that the installer of this dimmer switch wanted to do two-way switching, but either couldn't work out how to do it or didn't have a pull-switch at the other end that allowed it. Wiring for two-way switching would have required fitting the red/live wire to the common terminal, and use one yellow wire for each of L1 and L2. These two would then be connected (in whatever order) to the L1 and L2 terminals of the second switch.

Rather than use just one yellow wire (and then have to work out which is which at the other end), I think they opted to wire both together as switched lives, and leave it at that.

A look inside the pull switch might be interesting, to see if the yellow wires are connected together at that end too (assuming that they lead directly to the pull switch, and not via the light fittings). But whatever is done downstream, replacing the dimmer switch with a hard-wired connection (such as a Wago) will give you exactly the same functionality as with the dimmer switch in the full 'on' position.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer. Stupid question time, but what I can't wrap my head around is how connecting all three wires doesn't create a short. It obviously isn't a problem, since as you point out when the dimmer switch is on it is functionally equivalent, but would be good to understand more.

I will take a photo of the wiring of the pull switch tomorrow and update my question. Thanks again.

Comment: Connecting the three wires can only be a problem if the two yellow ones go to different places; if they go to the same place it's effectively a dual carriageway for electrons. It could still be OK if they do go to different places, e.g. half the LED lights are fed by one yellow wire, the rest fed by the other.